# How to use Ink recognize in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I am using .Net 4.0 WPF. I want to use InkCanvas to collect user input, then recognize what character is inputted. 
After googling, I found a solution in http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/ms754080.aspx
Unfortunately, it is for .net 3.5. Is there a solution for .net 4.0? Thanks.

===================

Download a TablePC SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20989
then got the Micorsoft.Ink.dll.  Below is the sample code...

```
    using Microsoft.Ink;
    using System.IO;
    private void btnGetInput_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (inkInput.Strokes.Count > 0)
        {
            System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection strokeList = inkInput.Strokes;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            inkInput.Strokes.Save(ms);
            InkCollector myInkCollector = new InkCollector();
            Ink ink = new Ink();
            ink.Load(ms.ToArray());

            using (RecognizerContext myRecoContext = new RecognizerContext())
            {
                RecognitionStatus status;
                RecognitionResult recoResult;
                myRecoContext.Strokes = ink.Strokes;
                recoResult = myRecoContext.Recognize(out status);
                tbUserName.Text += recoResult.TopString;
            }
            inkInput.Strokes.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Usually frameworks are forward compatible so if you find something which works in 3.5 it usually works in 4.0. Have you tried it out? Have you encounter some problems?

Comment: What makes you think that "it is for .net 3.5"? It works perfectly in a .Net 4 program.

Comment: System.Windows.Ink is exists in .net 3.5, it can't be found in .net 4.0 framework. It is what makes me think 'it is for .net 3.5'.

Comment: Thank God, I find a TablePC SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20989 and got the Microsoft.ink.dll, Now it can recognize my input.