# WPF - InkPresenter not found in InkCanvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm starting to get really confused by the different ways to recognizer text. Some are ancient and some are for Windows Forms or WPF ...

Today, if I only need to traget Windows 10 what Ink technology should I use?
I've been trying to use InkCanvas and all the docs talk about InkPresenter.
However InkPresenter is not a member of InkCanvas ...

[InkPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkpresenter)

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InkCanvas` is a WPF control and `InkPresenter` is a UWP control. Which one to use depends on what kind of application you are developing.

These are different kind of applications. A classic WPF desktop application runs on all Windows PCs including Windows 10 machines while Universal Windows Platforms (UWP) apps have the potential of running across all Windows 10 devices including phones, HoloLens and XBox: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide.

Comment: Strange this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788719(v=vs.110).aspx talks about the difference between WPF and COM but makes no mention of UWP.... So for recognition with WPF (not UWP) I still have to use Microsoft.Ink?

Comment: In WPF there is an InkCanvas control that allows you to copy, select, and resize ink: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, but no mention of text recognition.

Comment: You can write text on an InkCanvas area.

Comment: Yes - but how to recognize it as text.

Comment: Then you should be able to use Microsoft.Ink: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937820/how-to-use-ink-recognize-in-wpf

Comment: "InkPresenter is a UWP control" - there is a WPF InkPresenter as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx